# Quartz Composter — Recreate Audioskop (Adjust Video Time Based On Audio Input)

Tags: macos, audio, video, reactive-programming, quartz-composer

I'm looking for Audioskop (http://www.quartzcompositions.com/phpBB2/upload/details.php?file=390) yet it seems to have gone AWOL.

I've created a video (.mp4), and would like the video time to adjust based on audio input from my laptop mic. Using Quartz Composer.

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of a suitable tutorial or have a similar file that'll do the same job?

Enormous thanks and gratitude in advance, 
Gareth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audioskop V2 — http://qbus.fg.hs-wismar.de/?p=267

Out to Swen Hellmich!

Answer (score 0):

When you click the download link, it takes you here:

http://www.qbus.di.hs-wismar.de/wp-content/uploads/2006/07/Audioskop.zip

That link is broken, but a google search turned up what appears to be the same artist now over here: http://qbus.fg.hs-wismar.de/?page_id=30

I couldn't find that patch on his site, but his email is listed there. Perhaps he knows where it went :) Let me know if they fix the link, it looks cool.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasTeeple! I've just given him an email, I'll let you know what happens! I've got the video in now, projecting to a billboard. What I want to do is attach the lows of the audio processor to the Movie Position. Essentially randomly changing video position when a bass sound is picked up by the laptop mic.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1hvbbjmtgsvdwn/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-13%20at%2016.39.57.jpeg?dl=0